# How can I use diff to select times that are close together, but in an unknown range?

Tags: python, pandas

The following data set features gps time-stamps of buses arriving at a particular bus stop. While buses idle at the stop, gps transmitters continue to send data at semi-regular increments.

I'm trying to compile each bus' departure times from this one bus stop.  However, the complicating factor is, the same buses may repeat the route at roughly 2 hour intervals.

In the dataframe below, if the bus `NYCT_1202` stops at `10:01:19` in row `0` and remains at the stop until `10:11:48` in row `1`, I want to somehow select for `10:11:48`.

Similarly, after two hours,when the same bus has looped around to arrive at the stop again in row `2` at `12:51:31`, it "idles" (perhaps it was out of service) until `13:51:02`. I want to select for the last time, `13:51:02`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'RecordedAtTime': {0: Timestamp('2017-08-23 10:01:19'),
  1: Timestamp('2017-08-23 10:11:48'),
  2: Timestamp('2017-08-23 12:51:31'),
  3: Timestamp('2017-08-23 13:02:02'),
  4: Timestamp('2017-08-23 13:11:27'),
  5: Timestamp('2017-08-23 13:51:35'),
  6: Timestamp('2017-08-23 16:12:27'),
  7: Timestamp('2017-08-23 16:52:25'),
  8: Timestamp('2017-08-07 09:33:42'),
  9: Timestamp('2017-08-07 10:13:36')},
 'VehicleRef': {0: 'NYCT_1202',
  1: 'NYCT_1202',
  2: 'NYCT_1202',
  3: 'NYCT_1202',
  4: 'NYCT_1202',
  5: 'NYCT_1202',
  6: 'NYCT_1202',
  7: 'NYCT_1202',
  8: 'NYCT_1206',
  9: 'NYCT_1206'}})

       RecordedAtTime VehicleRef
0 2017-08-23 10:01:19  NYCT_1202
1 2017-08-23 10:11:48  NYCT_1202 <-This Row

2 2017-08-23 12:51:31  NYCT_1202
3 2017-08-23 13:02:02  NYCT_1202
4 2017-08-23 13:11:27  NYCT_1202
5 2017-08-23 13:51:35  NYCT_1202 <-This Row

6 2017-08-23 16:12:27  NYCT_1202
7 2017-08-23 16:52:25  NYCT_1202 <-This Row

8 2017-08-07 09:33:42  NYCT_1206
9 2017-08-07 10:13:36  NYCT_1206 <-This Row
```

If the buses didn't loop back around, I could use `df.groupby(by=['VehicleRef','RecordedAtTime']).last` to select for the last time.

I also tried creating a `TimeDelta` column with `df['TimeDelta']=df['RecordedAtTime'].diff` so I could apply `df.loc[lambda x: x['TimeDelta']>2]`. However, `diff` doesn't produce the difference between the 0th and 1st times in row 0, which means I can't select rows by their time deltas.

```
       RecordedAtTime VehicleRef          timeDelta
0 2017-08-23 10:01:19  NYCT_1202                NaT <-Should be 00:10:29
1 2017-08-23 10:11:48  NYCT_1202    0 days 00:10:29 <-Should be 02:39:43

2 2017-08-23 12:51:31  NYCT_1202    0 days 02:39:43
3 2017-08-23 13:02:02  NYCT_1202    0 days 00:10:31
4 2017-08-23 13:11:27  NYCT_1202    0 days 00:09:25
5 2017-08-23 13:51:35  NYCT_1202    0 days 00:40:08 <-Should be 02:20:52

6 2017-08-23 16:12:27  NYCT_1202    0 days 02:20:52
7 2017-08-23 16:52:25  NYCT_1202    0 days 00:39:58 <-Should be +16:41:17

8 2017-08-07 09:33:42  NYCT_1206 -17 days +16:41:17
9 2017-08-07 10:13:36  NYCT_1206    0 days 00:39:54 <-Should be next difference
```

So what pandas library could I use to solve this problem? Is there a better way to use `.diff` or should I approach this problem in an entirely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime as datetime

# Approximate trip duration
trip_minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 90)

# Ensure ordering by time grouped by vehicle
df  = df.sort_values('RecordedAtTime')
dfg = df.groupby('VehicleRef')

# Elapsed time interval is the difference, within vehicle group
df['Elapsed'] = dfg['RecordedAtTime'].diff()

# Elapsed time close to the trip time indicates a trip ending
df['isEnd'] = df['Elapsed'] > trip_minutes

# The start is the row just before the last end - use shift  within group
df['isStart'] = dfg['isEnd'].shift(-1)

# select the rows ensuring that a NaN start event is included
df[df['isStart'] != False]
```

Results:

```
       RecordedAtTime VehicleRef  Elapsed  isEnd isStart
9 2017-08-07 10:13:36  NYCT_1206 00:39:54  False     NaN
1 2017-08-23 10:11:48  NYCT_1202 00:10:29  False    True
5 2017-08-23 13:51:35  NYCT_1202 00:40:08  False    True
7 2017-08-23 16:52:25  NYCT_1202 00:39:58  False     NaN
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your output for some reason (row 7 was missing). However, After placing  
`df.loc[df['Elapsed'].isnull(),'isEnd'] = True` before `df['isStart'] = dfg['isEnd'].shift(-1)`, I got exactly the same rows as in your comment. Thanks so much!